# change the canvas UI in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I created a canvas app using heroku account, and deployed a war file to it. Now I am accessing it in my salesforce account.I want to add an input field(text) to this app in salesforce. Is it possible to make this happen in salesforce? If yes, how?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "UI is not good". Could you elaborate on that, possibly add an image.

Comment: Canvas merely surfaces an external app in Salesforce. For any UI improvements, you'd have to do this on the original app.

Comment: I want to add a text field in the app while being in salesforce. If u can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying your Canvas App by using a Visualforce page, you would be able to add a Visualforce input field without issue:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Field" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
                <apex:canvasApp developerName="MyCanvasApp"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This would show the Account Name field and below that would show your canvas app.  Providing fit and finish so that everything looks seamless would be a different exercise.

Now, if you want to pass information about the field into the canvas app, you can do that as of Spring '14 by using the Visualforce<->Eventing.  See page 46 of the Canvas Developer Guide - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/canvas_framework.pdf

Hope this helps